# What version of spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream is compatible with Kafka 1.0.0

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

When trying to run a slightly adapted version of word-count [example](https://github.com/mbogoevici/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream/tree/master/kstream-samples/kstream-word-count), I am having an error that says *"No qualifying bean of type'org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStreamBuilder'"*. In my POM, I am using  **spring-cloud-stream-dependencies:Elmhurst.M3** to import dependencies, which imported **spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream:2.0.0.M3**.

However, I don't think I did anything special :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(KStreamProcessor.class)
public class KafkaExampleSpringcloud1Application {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaExampleSpringcloud1Application.class, 
        args);

    }

    @Autowired
    private TimeWindows timeWindows;

    @StreamListener("input")
    @SendTo("output")
    public KStream<?, WordCount> process(KStream<Object, String> input) {

        return input
                .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
                .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value, value))
                .groupByKey(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())
                .count(timeWindows, "WordCounts")
                .toStream()
                .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(null, new WordCount(key.key(), value, new Date(key.window().start()), new Date(key.window().end()))));
    }



    static class WordCount {

        private String word;

        private long count;

        private Date start;

        private Date end;

        WordCount(String word, long count, Date start, Date end) {
            this.word = word;
            this.count = count;
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        public String getWord() {
            return word;
        }

        public void setWord(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }

        public long getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public void setCount(long count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        public Date getStart() {
            return start;
        }

        public void setStart(Date start) {
            this.start = start;
        }

        public Date getEnd() {
            return end;
        }

        public void setEnd(Date end) {
            this.end = end;
        }
    }
```

Here is my application.yml:

```
application.name: kafka-example-01
spring.cloud.stream:
  kstream:
    configuration:
      commit.interval.ms: 1000
      key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
      value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    timeWindow.length: 5000
    binder:
      brokers: localhost
      zkNodes: localhost
  kafka:
    binder:
      autoCreateTopics: false
  bindings:
    output.destination: word-count-output
    input.destnation : word-count-input
```

I tried to used older versions, but I keep having ClassNotFoundException errors (e.g. StreamsBuilder class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently in a milestone, just 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. It will be in M4.

[Commit here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/50b8955dfc6330c150195d84a9c64c1ba95b0bef#diff-611514670b52df7653bdfb6f2c55aec7).

Comment: I tried with 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and I am having ClassNotFoundException on StreamsBuilderFactoryBean. For the other dependencies, I tried both Elmhurst.M3 and Elmhurst.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and got the same result.

Comment: Unfortunately, with all the prescriptive dependency management stuff provided by spring boot and spring cloud, there's a bunch of versions you have to override. See the notes at the bottom of [the project page](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) about overriding to use kafka 11 with 1.3.x. In this case, you need spring-kafka 2.1.1, spring-integration-kafka 3.0.0, spring-integration-* 5.0.0.

Comment: Now that Spring Cloud Stream 2.0.0.M4 is released, the example works just fine. Besides, Spring Cloud Stream 2.0.0.M4 is already the managed version in Spring Cloud Finchley M6.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with these:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```